# server get full memory when compiling assets

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I have a RorR app running on EC2 (micro insntance, ~590mb mem.).
When I deploy the app with capistrano, memory usage hits aroun 98,7% when assets are beign compile...
Is there a way to reduce this usage?

this is my deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :application, "name"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:user/app.git"

set :scm, :git

role :web, "server.compute.amazonaws.com" 
role :app, "server.compute.amazonaws.com" 
role :db,  "server.compute.amazonaws.com", :primary => true

set :user, "user"
set :use_sudo, false

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
ssh_options[:keys] = ["#{ENV['HOME']}/key.pem"]

# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

set :deploy_to, "/home/user"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

role :web, "server.compute.amazonaws.com" # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "server.compute.amazonaws.com" # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db, "server.compute.amazonaws.com", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts
```

is this an expect behavior? Should I increase memory?
I was using a VM on digitalocean.com with 256mb, now i'm using EC2 with 590mb, and the consumption still hits almost 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Rails 3.1.1, then your problem is probably associated with this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3694. It has been fixed in rails 3.2, so upgrading should solve your problem.